# Dual monitor bug on Ubuntu 19.10 live USB

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, live-usb

I'm currently having an odd problem with a Ubuntu 19.10 live USB. I currently have a dual monitor setup, my secondary monitor is to the left of my main one. By default, Ubuntu puts the secondary monitor on the right, so I moved it to the left. However, when I do this everything that's being displayed on my main monitor becomes displayed on the left one, but the areas where you can click are still on the main one.

I'd like to know if there's a way to fix this, and if this problem persists on an actual full install of Ubuntu.

My GPU is an Nvidia RTX 2070

Comment: Try to install Ubuntu on lets say external drive or even on main PC drive. I have been using Ubuntu on dual, and trio monitor setup and I have never ran into issue like that, maybe it is due to fact that it is live USB or combination of liveUSB and hardware. So please can you [edit] your question and provide info about graphic card,  (I asume that your device is a laptop,so laptop model then).                                                                              Have you maybe tried Ubuntu 18.04 LTS liveUSB (or other version maybe) and was it fine or the same?

Comment: @V.H. I am using a Nvidia RTX 2070, I have not tried it with the LTS version yet, I am doing that right now.

Comment: @V.H. The LTS version of the live USB simply goes to a black screen when the orientation is changed. It does not revert automatically after 30 seconds.

Comment: Probabaly it is due to LiveUSB, and drivers. So it should not be the case on actual install. You can install it and then go to Software and Updates>drivers>  and then switch to Nvidia drivers. You have a detailed guide on following link: www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/amp/